# What does the "cdw" do exactly in the canned Search for "Recents"?

Tags: macos, spotlight, microsoft

The Finder's sidebar search for "Recents" (in High Sierra) is a raw query, which can be found here:
            `/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Resources/MyLibraries/myDocuments.cannedSearch/Resources/search.savedSearch`.

The query string goes like this:

```
(kMDItemLastUsedDate = "*") &amp;&amp; ((kMDItemContentTypeTree = public.content) || (kMDItemContentTypeTree = "com.microsoft.*"cdw) || (kMDItemContentTypeTree = public.archive))
```

This also looks for Microsoft stuff.  The relevant part of the query is:
    `kMDItemContentTypeTree = "com.microsoft.*"cdw`

What does the "cdw" part of this query accomplish?  And what does it stand for?

I found another mention here for `mdfind` usage:
https://gist.github.com/cwalston/7425465

```
!   -interpret        Force the provided query string to be interpreted as if the user
!                     had typed the string into the Spotlight menu.
!                     For example, the string "search" would produce the following
!                     query string:
!                     (* = search* cdw || kMDItemTextContent = search* cdw)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cdw is an abbreviation for these search queries with this functions:

c: Case insensitive

d: Diacritical insensitive

w: Word-based, and detects transitions from lower- to uppercase

Source:

[Mac OS X Snow Leopard for Power Users: Advanced Capabilities and Techniques by Scott Granneman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430230304)

Answer (score 2):

The **cdw** at the end of the query string means the comparison should ignore **c**ase, **d**iacritics, and **w**idth (which is mostly relevant for text with Asian characters).

1st source: [How can I find files by content in mac os x?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36076447/4100967)

> Use this modifier... To specify a comparison that is...
>   c                             Case insensitive.
>   d                             Insensitive to diacritical marks.
>   w                            Word-based. In addition, the comparison detects transitions from lower-case
>                                  to upper-case.
>   t                              Performed on the tokenized value. For example, values passed directly from
>                                  a search field are tokenized.

2nd source: [CSSearchQuery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corespotlight/cssearchquery)

Comment: Thank you very much klanomath. I'm slightly confused about the discrepancy between "width" and "word-based" for the "w" in your answer.

Comment: @Redarm Me too, two sources with slightly different explanantions...