How can I reset the "Recents" search criteria in Finder?
Somehow I deleted the search criteria for the "Recents" Sidebar entry.
What is the default search criteria used by "Recents" and how can I restore it?




cat /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Resources/MyLibraries/myDocuments.cannedSearch/Resources/search.savedSearch

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>CompatibleVersion</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>RawQuery</key>
        <string>(kMDItemLastUsedDate = "*") &amp;&amp; ((kMDItemContentTypeTree = public.content) || (kMDItemContentTypeTree = "com.microsoft.*"cdw) || (kMDItemContentTypeTree = public.archive))</string>
        <key>RawQueryDict</key>
        <dict>
            <key>FinderFilesOnly</key>
            <true/>
            <key>RawQuery</key>
            <string>(kMDItemLastUsedDate = "*") &amp;&amp; ((kMDItemContentTypeTree = public.content) || (kMDItemContentTypeTree = "com.microsoft.*"cdw) || (kMDItemContentTypeTree = public.archive))</string>
            <key>SearchScopes</key>
            <array>
            <string>kMDQueryScopeMyFiles</string>
            </array>
            <key>UserFilesOnly</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>SearchCriteria</key>
        <dict>
            <key>AnyAttributeContains</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>CurrentFolderPath</key>
            <array>
                <string>/Users</string>
            </array>
            <key>FXCriteriaSlices</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>criteria</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>com_apple_RawQueryAttribute</string>
                        <integer>104</integer>
                    </array>
                    <key>displayValues</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>Raw query</string>
                        <string>(kMDItemLastUsedDate = "*") &amp;&amp; ((kMDItemContentTypeTree = public.content) || (kMDItemContentTypeTree = "com.microsoft.*"cdw) || (kMDItemContentTypeTree = public.archive))</string>
                    </array>
                    <key>rowType</key>
                    <integer>0</integer>
                    <key>subrows</key>
                    <array/>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>FXScope</key>
            <integer>1396925814</integer>
            <key>FXScopeArrayOfPaths</key>
            <array>
              <string>kMDQueryScopeMyFiles</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    </plist>

EDIT: add screenshot which illustrates that the search query is lost.
EDIT2: add screenshot which illustrates that the raw query cannot be saved.
EDIT3: add search.savedSearch content.

Doubtful that you deleted anything.  Recents is a "canned search", packed into Finder.app and protected by the system.

The string goes: (kMDItemLastUsedDate = "*") && ((kMDItemContentTypeTree = public.content) || (kMDItemContentTypeTree = "com.microsoft.*"cdw) || (kMDItemContentTypeTree = public.archive)) If you right (or option) click the "Recents" in the grey box in your screenshot, you can choose to "Show Search Criteria".

See also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/303318/what-does-the-cdw-do-exactly-in-the-canned-search-for-recents

@Redarm thanks I added the raw query, now its working again. But I cannot save it..

Did you look for the savedSearch in the location given in the link I'd posted?  What does open /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Resources/MyLibraries/myDocuments.cannedSearch/Resources/search.savedSearch in Terminal give you?

Yes, I saw it. I added search.savedSearch content.

Seems fine to me.  If you open it via Terminal (as per my last comment), do you not get the default "Recents" search?  Seems more an issue with Finder than the search string.  I assume you've tried restarting, or at least killing Finder?

Looking in Terminal I see that "search.savedSearch" is "restricted", belongs to root (and group wheel) with -rw-r--r-- permissions, which is why I doubted that you deleted, or changed it by accident.  As long as you are not trying to hack your system I would expect it to work again after a reboot.

Thanks @Redarm, you are right, after a restart "Recents" again shows files.
